# How to parse Spring-format application.properties file outside Spring application (like in a gradle build script)?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, gradle

I have a Spring Boot application containing an application.properties file. Spring's properties handling lets me do things like

```
property1=my-value-${ENV_VARIABLE1}
property2=${property1}-extended
```

Now I need some of those properties (database name, etc) from this properties file in the Gradle build script to generate JOOQ classes. Using the regular Java properties parser works for simple .properties files, but doesn't support Spring's extensions like properties files referencing each other and environment variables.

Is there a way to parse a properties file like Spring would do?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this recently and found it surprising that there is no straightforward way to achieve this functionality. I even opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35852) with Spring Boot, but the feature was deemed too complex to implement.

Nevertheless, I've made a proof of concept that supports multiple Spring profiles, precedence and variable interpolation together with ENV variable overriding. It's not the cleanest and doesn't mirror Spring Boot entirely, but it should have you covered for most cases. This is how I integrated it in my build.gradle file:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir ("src/main/java")
            srcDir ("build/generated/sources")
        }
    }
}

// Rest of build.gradle

// Extract properties as Spring Boot would
StandardEnvironment springBootEnvironment = new StandardEnvironment();
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
String activeProfilesEnvVariable = "$System.env.spring_profiles_active"
String[] profiles = activeProfilesEnvVariable.split(",")
println "Active spring profiles: " + profiles
if (activeProfilesEnvVariable != "null" && profiles.length != 0) {
    for (final def profile in profiles) {
        for (final def resDir in sourceSets.main.getResources().srcDirs) {
            String searchPath = Paths.get("file:" + resDir.toString(), "application-" + profile + ".properties").toString()
            var resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(searchPath)
            for (final def res in resources) {
                springBootEnvironment.getPropertySources().addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(res))
            }
        }
    }
}
springBootEnvironment
        .getPropertySources()
        .addLast(
                new ResourcePropertySource(
                        resourcePatternResolver.getResource("file:src/main/resources/application.properties")
                )
        )

// Use a property
springBootEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")
```

As you can see, most of the code deals with the precedence and discovery of properties files. If you use yaml property files, you can use the `YamlPropertySourceLoader`.
You'd run gradle with the `spring_profiles_active` ENV variable set to whichever profile(s) you want, just like with your Spring Boot app