# Replicate the way Spring Boot parses properties by default, outside of Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159509/how-to-parse-spring-format-application-properties-file-outside-spring-applicatio) (no answers), but more general.
I'm looking to replicate the way Spring Boot parses properties, but outside of a running Spring Aplication, for example in gradle, so I can use the properties in a task.
In short, this means passing the profile name(s) and following the same precedence logic like in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

From what I've gathered, an instance of `Environment` is the first step, but I can't get much further than that. Ideally I'd just call the same code path that the Spring Boot runtime calls when starting an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I will simply copy my answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159509/how-to-parse-spring-format-application-properties-file-outside-spring-applicatio) I referenced above:*

I was struggling with this recently and found it surprising that there is no straightforward way to achieve this functionality. I even opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35852) with Spring Boot, but the feature was deemed too complex to implement.

Nevertheless, I've made a proof of concept that supports multiple Spring profiles, precedence and variable interpolation together with ENV variable overriding. It's not the cleanest and doesn't mirror Spring Boot entirely, but it should have you covered for most cases. This is how I integrated it in my build.gradle file:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir ("src/main/java")
            srcDir ("build/generated/sources")
        }
    }
}

// Rest of build.gradle

// Extract properties as Spring Boot would
StandardEnvironment springBootEnvironment = new StandardEnvironment();
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
String activeProfilesEnvVariable = "$System.env.spring_profiles_active"
String[] profiles = activeProfilesEnvVariable.split(",")
println "Active spring profiles: " + profiles
if (activeProfilesEnvVariable != "null" && profiles.length != 0) {
    for (final def profile in profiles) {
        for (final def resDir in sourceSets.main.getResources().srcDirs) {
            String searchPath = Paths.get("file:" + resDir.toString(), "application-" + profile + ".properties").toString()
            var resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(searchPath)
            for (final def res in resources) {
                springBootEnvironment.getPropertySources().addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(res))
            }
        }
    }
}
springBootEnvironment
        .getPropertySources()
        .addLast(
                new ResourcePropertySource(
                        resourcePatternResolver.getResource("file:src/main/resources/application.properties")
                )
        )

// Use a property
springBootEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")
```

As you can see, most of the code deals with the precedence and discovery of properties files. If you use yaml property files, you can use the `YamlPropertySourceLoader`.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not implement all of the property sources in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). It implements enough to read an application properties file from the class path:

```java
var environment = new StandardEnvironment();
var resource = new ClassPathResource("application.yml");
PropertySource<?> propertySource;
try {
  var propertySources = new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.toString(), resource);
  propertySource = propertySources.get(0);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load file " + resource, e);
}

environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
environment.setActiveProfiles(ACTIVE_PROFILE);
```

Comment: I'm trying to build something more involved on top of what you provided, but the class loader can't find a file in the resources dir with the error `class path resource [application.properties] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`